# uib-popover unexpectedly closes with "outsideClick" and uib-datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

uib-Popover unexpectedly closes with popover-template, "outsideClick" trigger and a uib-Datepicker in it: in fact, the popover unexpectedly closes when clicking on the datepicker itself.

Here the button opening the popover:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button uib-popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'" popover-title="Popover title" type="button" class="btn btn-default" popover-trigger="outsideClick" popover-placement="bottom" >Open me</button>
</div>
```

and the popover template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
    <div class="form-group">
      <uib-datepicker ng-model="dateTime" class="well well-sm"></uib-datepicker>
    </div>
    {{dateTime | date}}
</script>
```

full code in plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/ESto8dgDbh52g0nl7g03/

Is this a bug of angular bootstrap or i am missing something? i already opened an issue on angular bootstrap github, you can follow it here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this is already been [aswered](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5628) on github.

Below i will share the answer from wesleycho, one of the main contributors of angular bootstrap:

> You have to manually stop the click event propagation.

More pratically, you need to add a

```
 ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

on the parent element of the uib-datepicker.

A quick example of this solution can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ML8Uxdsl6ByX87bGZxie?p=preview)  (provided by wesleycho itself).